# Site home URL is re-directing to local server URL after remote database import and file upload via FTP

Tags: wordpress, database-migration

I dropped my remote database in order to import a new one and, at the same time, re-uploaded my WordPress/WooCommerce site via FTP (File Zilla).

The problem is that my live site (www.site.com) is now re-directing to my local URL (www.site.dev.cc) on the homepage only.  All other pages, e.g. wp-login and blog work fine.  I have tried making the change in settings > general; editing the functions.php file and wp-config file but no luck.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?  I changed site URL in `wp_settings` in the remote database to www.site.com but that doesn't seem to have helped.

[image: the top of my database in phpmyadmin]

I have re-named items in the database from www.site.dev.cc to www.site.com but it hasn't worked, which makes me wonder if its something in one of the file that was uploaded.

Any ideas welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My site was being cached - it's now been solved

Answer (score 2):

Run following SQL queries on **Remote DB Server**:

```
-- Change Siteurl & Homeurl
UPDATE `allstar_allst.wp_options` SET `option_value` = replace(option_value, 'www.site.dev.cc', 'www.site.com') WHERE `option_name` = 'home' OR `option_name` = 'siteurl';

-- Change GUID
UPDATE `allstar_allst.wp_posts` SET `guid` = REPLACE (guid, 'www.site.dev.cc', 'www.site.com');

-- Change URL in Content
UPDATE `allstar_allst.wp_posts` SET `post_content` = REPLACE (post_content, 'www.site.dev.cc', 'www.site.com');

-- Change Image Path Only
UPDATE `allstar_allst.wp_posts` SET `post_content` = REPLACE (post_content, 'src="www.site.dev.cc"', 'src="www.site.com"');

UPDATE `allstar_allst.wp_posts` SET `guid` = REPLACE (guid, 'www.site.dev.cc', 'www.site.com') WHERE `post_type` = 'attachment';

-- Update Post Meta
UPDATE `allstar_allst.wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value` = REPLACE (meta_value, 'www.site.dev.cc', 'www.site.com');
```

---

**Note**

1. Replace `www.site.dev.cc` with your local dev site
2. Replace `www.site.com` with your actual site's URL

---

**Edit**

All the queries are prefixed with the db name.

Comment: thanks kashif - just to check: when you say replace wp_ with my db table name, are you referring to a specific wp_ ? it would strike me as odd to replace them all e.g. wp_posts to dbname_posts

Comment: @J4G If your database table name is `wp` then all is good. There is no need to change it. Skip the 1st point in my note above and do the remaining 2 points. You are good to go ahead.

Comment: my db name is allstar_alls, i tried running the query but to no avail (without making a change to wp_). for example, should wp_postmeta be allstar_alls_postmeta even though the table is wp_postmeta? sorry if this doesn't make sense, it's not my strong suit

Comment: Whats' the table name of your database? Is it `wp` or something else?

Comment: This might sound silly but I’m not sure - i have added a screenshot to my original question. does that help?

Comment: @J4G Check the updated queries in the answer. I hope it will work for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183038/discussion-between-j4g-and-kashif-rafique).